# Call child api after parent api Angular

Tags: angular, rest, api

I'm with a problem that is:
I have 2 entities, child and parent and each has its own api and is an one-to-many relationship. The parent component has the child component inside it, so during the creation of a new parent, the user can create the children too. My question is, how can I hold the creation (api call) of the child until the parent is created, so that I can get the parentId generated in the back-end and put into my child then create it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use *ngIf on the parent template where it renders the child components.

For example, in the parent component

```
<div class="I-AM-PARENT">
    <child-component *ngIf="parentId" [parentId]="parentId"></child-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I create the parent and the child at the same time, for example: book and comments. Each has its own api, and it's a one-to-many relationship, so when creating the book I can add comments to if at the same time. How can I hold the comment api call (POST) to be runned after the book? As I need the book to be created first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mergeMap` to wait for the first API call to complete before making the new request. You can make the first call and the result of it will be available in the mergeMap block for use in next call.

```
this.httpClient.post('bookApiUrl', { bookData }).mergeMap(bookApiResponse => {
  // Perform any operation on bookApiResponse
  // Extract book id from bookApiResponse for use in next API call
  return this.httpClient.post('commentApiUrl', { commentData })
}).subscribe(commentApiResponse => {
  // Perform any operation on commentApiResponse
});
```